# Sum of the smaller value between two columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

[i want to find the sum of a row based only by the cells with a value smaller than the row below them.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLRvs.png)

So, i want to have the sum of all the cells of the row B14:R14, that are smaller than the cell below.

Ex: B14:D14 are bigger than the cells below(B15:D15) but E14 and G14 is smaller so I sum all of them.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, could you be more specific and share some sample, and see where exactly do you struggle'

Comment: Your title asks for something like this `=SUM(IF(B2:B7<=D2:D7,B2:B7,D2:D7))` while the following asks for something like this `=SUM(IF(H2:M2<H3:M3,H2:M2,0))`. Which is it?

Comment: I sorry for the wait. i updated my question

Comment: Then it should be my 2nd suggestion: `=SUM(IF($B14:$R14<$B15:$R15,$B14:$R14,0))`. If not, lets us know what's wrong with it.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I just want the sum of the cells that are smaller than the cells bellow

Comment: This is an array formula. If you have an older Office version, when you see `SUM`, there are usually two possibilities to make it work: either use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM`, or confirm the `SUM` formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (instead of just `Enter`) i.e. hold down `Ctrl+Shift` and press `Enter` which will show the formula in the formula bar in braces (`{}`).

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you it work now. I just did the sum of this formula for the two columns like this :  =ArrayFormula(SUM(IF($B14:$R14<$B15:$R15,$B14:$R14,0)))+ArrayFormula(SUM(IF($B15:$R15<$B14:$R14,B15:R15,0)))'

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?:

[image]

using the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E5:E16,N(E5:E16<E6:E17))
```

or in a slightly more elegant way written as

```
=SUMPRODUCT(E5:E16,N(E5:E16<OFFSET(E5:E16,1,0)))
```

Although it should be noted that the `OFFSET()` function is a [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#volatile-and-non-volatile-functions) function